# UnityContainer: Conditional Logic upon resolving

Tags: unity-container, ioc-container, containers

I have an interface with 3 different implementations. I register the 3 implementations as named aliases in the Web.config of the Web application using Unity Container.

Is there a way using Unity, to resolve one of the registered instance, based on some logic. the logic includes contacting a DB to decide on which implementation to be resolved.

Appreciate your help.

Regards
Bilal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the logic in an abstract factory and inject it:

```
public interface IMyInterface { }

public interface IMyInterfaceFactory {
   IMyInterface GetMyInterface();
}

public class MyInterfaceFactory : IMyInterfaceFactory  {
       private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
       public MyInterfaceFactory(IUnityContainer container) { 
           _container = container; }

       IMyInterface GetMyInterface() {
            var impName = Get_implementation_name_from_db();
            return container.Resolve<IMyInterface>(impName);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. I preferred the second approach as it is more SOC.

Comment: Hi Onof, question please on the above. In case One of the methods inside "IMyInterface" requires some input. In my application, I have a ICacheManager that is registered with Unity. Is it better to pass in the parameters one by one to the method or let the method use the ICacheManager to retrieve data? Unit testing or separation of concerns point of view, which is recommended? Thanks

Comment: IMO your component should be unaware of cache: you should be able to use it in a different context where there is no cache available.

Comment: But then I am not using the power of DI? It also has a reference to ILogger.

Comment: I'm not saying you have not to use DI, i'm saying you should not inject ICacheManager into the component. I would inject a "IMyParameterProvider" and would implement a MyCachedParameterProvider extending IMyParameterProvider and i would inject the cache manager inside it.

Comment: Hi Onof, actually ICacheManager that I have is simply a cache manager around HttpContext.Current.Items collection. It plays the role of parameter provider but for the entire application. So what you are saying is that I create a parameter provider with the parameters needed by my main Interface implementation? Also, what if a method inside my interface needs to update the application cache? shall it return that value and let the application code dealing with that component update the cache? Is this the right way? thanks a lot.

Comment: It depends. If the component is responsible to update the cache (it's a cache related component) I would make it having a dependency on ICacheManager. If no, I would make it dependent only of a IMyParameterProvider.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a 'router' implementation that knows how to route the requests to one of the other implementations:

```
// Here is a possible implementation of the router. There are 
// of course many ways to do this.
public class MyRouterImpl : IMyInterface
{
    List<IMyInterface> implementations = new List<IMyInterface>();

    public MyRouterImpl(MyImpl1 i1, MyImpl2 i2, MyImpl3 i3)
    {
        this.implementations.Add(i1);
        this.implementations.Add(i2);
        this.implementations.Add(i3);
    }

    void IMyInterface.Method()
    {
        int indexOfImplementationToExecute = 
            GetIndexOfImplementationToExecute();

        IMyInterface impl =
            this.implementations[indexOfImplementationToExecute];

        impl.Method();
    }
}
```